# condition_variable event notifyAndWait()

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a loop that waits for the event.

I want to be able to add a `notifyAndWait()` function

Im not to sure how i can add that to my current class

```
class Event
{
public:

    Event() : _signalled(false) {}

    void notify()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _signalled = true;
        _condvar.notify_one();
    }

    void wait()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
        _condvar.wait(lock, [&] { return _signalled; }); // also takes care about spurious wakeup
        _signalled = false; // auto-reset semantics
    }

private:

    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _condvar;
    bool _signalled;
};
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. You obviously have some code here that uses a condition variable. Did you have some problem with what you've already written so far? Otherwise, how does the code relate to the question? Is it not a simple matter of calling `notify()` to notify, and `wait()` to wait?

Comment: it forks fine for now, but im trying to call notify() but wait for it to be finished

Comment: So now you want to notify _and_ wait on the same thread? Or something else?

Comment: By the way, `_signalled` needs to be an `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: yes i want the thread that calls notify to be able to wait for the event to be finished once its notified .

Comment: Okay well depending on what else is going on in your program there are a number of ways to do it. If the thread ends after being notified then you can just join it. Otherwise, you can wait to re-lock `_mutex`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `_signalled` doesn't need to be atomic, it's protected by `mutex`

Comment: the thread does not end after being notified, the thread just waits to be notified, but sometimes when i notify the thread i want to wait for the thread to do its thing.

Comment: If you wait for the event to complete, then why signal in the first place? Why not just call the event handling code from the thread you want to wait on?

Comment: @Galik Because i sometimes need to wait for that thread most of the time i dont

Comment: Can't you just use a second `Event` instance for that?

Comment: @liliscent: Er, yes, that is true. I was thinking of when people are using atomics but _don't_ lock them (which they do still need to do before notifying) 

Comment: @super but shouldnt i be able to do it from the same event? seems silly to have a 2nd event to check if the event has been notified and finished

Comment: @ciyaso You probably can depending on your use case. If there's only 2 threads involved just `wait` in the thread that called notify, and `notify` from the thread that was waiting.

Comment: You could just use the same condition variable in reverse with a new flag `_completed`.

Comment: @Galik and how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same *condition variable* to pass a signal back to the calling thread, using a different flag. Something like this:

```
class Event
{
public:

    Event() : _signalled(false) {}

    void notify()
    {
        std::cout << "notifying" << '\n' << std::flush;

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _completed = false;
            _signalled = true;
        }

        _condvar.notify_one();

        {
            // now wait for completion
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _condvar.wait(lock, [&] { return _completed; });
        }

        std::cout << "completed" << '\n' << std::flush;
    }

    void wait()
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _condvar.wait(lock, [&] { return _signalled; });
            _signalled = false;
        }

        // do stuff

        auto n = hol::random_number(10);

        std::cout << "doing " << n << " different things" << std::flush;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << '.' << std::flush;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(hol::random_number(3000)));
        }
        std::cout << " done stuff" << '\n' << std::flush;

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _completed = true;
        }

        _condvar.notify_one();
    }

private:

    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _condvar;
    bool _signalled;
    bool _completed;
};

int main()
{
    Event e;

    std::thread wait([&]{ e.wait(); });

    e.notify();

    wait.join();
}
```

Comment: hi, its not quite what i was looking for, i didnt really want my stuff to be ran in the event class. im trying to change my class to add `notifyCompleted()` and `notifyAndWait()` from looking at your code, but my program freezes not sure why.